# Azure pipeline - How to specify auto retry on failure builds

Tags: azure-devops

In Jenkins CI, there's a plugin to "Retry build after failure", where we can specify number of times we want the build to auto trigger when job fails.

Does something similar in Azure Devops, where the pipeline will auto trigger when build fails?

Answer (score 33):

It seems possible since November 2021 to retry a failing task, at least in YAML pipelines.

Docs: [Automatic retries for a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-195-update#automatic-retries-for-a-task)

```yaml
- task: <name of task>
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: <max number of retries>
```

While this is not retrying the whole pipeline, it might be enough for many use cases.

Comment: Appreciate your Response. Thanks for letting me know. Yes. This is good enough for my implementation.

Comment: This also supports classic pipelines. From the docs: *When using classic build or release pipelines, you can set this property under the control options for the task.*

Comment: Also to add my 2¢: I used a number as the value which works e.g. `retryCountOnTaskFailure: 1` since the type isn't specified in the link/answer. Maybe a string also works? But a number definitely works!

Comment: @paweł-bulwan This task retry on failure is working, but I'm seeing the overall pipeline is still marked as failed even if it retried and succeeded on the second run.  Is there a known workaround for that?

Answer (score 10):

At present, In the Azure Devops, we do not have such auto retry option.

You can view the user voice ticket here [Rerun failed build task/step](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/rerun-failed-build-taskstep/365697):

But there is a rest api you can specify `?retry=true`:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{ProjectID}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildID}?retry=true
```

Which will help re-run the failed job.

I created a PowerShell demo:

```
$connectionToken="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
  
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 
    -Uri 'https://dev.azure.com/MyCustomOrganization/MyTestProject/_apis/build/builds/7364?retry=true&api-version=6.0'
    -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
    -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    -Method PATCH
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this rerun api should work. Do you mind if I ask how to call this rest api using powershell? Does it need a body or just URL is enough??
Please suggest.

Comment: Great! @ram You could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @YujunDing-MSFT I've tried your approach by setting a second stage tha runs if the first failed, which resulted in the following error: `Unable to retry pipeline 20210810.6 because it is not currently in the completed state`. Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2):

For classic release pipelines there is a retry option nowadays:

[image]

Comment: I set mine to 3 and it still stops on the first error. In my case it's PowerShell exited with code '1'. Do I also need to enable Continue on error?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not able to retry the build from a running pipeline by rest api "builds", you could consider using "pipelines" to run a new build by using same pipeline id and branch.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

I used it like this in a powershell script, notice that I run it from localhost and you should use other means of authorization if not:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:8080/tfs/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/$($env:System_DefinitionId)/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -Method POST -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json" -Body @"
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "$($env:Build_SourceBranch)"
            }
        }
    }
}
"@
```