# In AzurePipelines.yml file using (task: DotNetCoreCLI@2) is it possible to add an argument to rerun failed tests

Tags: testing, azure-pipelines, xunit, specflow

This is what I have working in place at the moment on the pipeline.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Run API Scenarios
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '**/*Myproject.csproj'
      arguments: '--filter Category=Portfolio'
      testRunTitle: 'API Test Execution'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't think there's anything specific for tests themselves, there is:

```
- task: <name of task>
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: <max number of retries>
```

[Link to similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910269/azure-pipeline-how-to-specify-auto-retry-on-failure-builds)

Although, you may want to add some retry mechanism in your tests if it's a flaky API test.